# Connection is no secure say in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

1. Mozilla firefox Url Show Connection is not Secure

[image]

> Google Chrome Show url (Nut Secure)
>
> [image]
>
> This is **asp.net application**. when i execute this solution .Browser say that your connection is not secure.
>
> Q 1. Which type is the problem?
>
> Q 2. Who to solve this?
>
> Q 3. How to find out/check the Browser(because I know that browser only get client script)?

Note: I need to know detail information about this issue.

Comment: So something is not https on the page

Answer (score 2):

That is not an error. It is just a warning telling the user that the page is not secure as it is not being server over a secure connection i.e. **HTTPS**. All requests that are served over an http connection example http://example.com are known as insecure requests. All requests served over a secure https connection example https://example.com are secure connection.

In order to make your site secure you should buy an SSL certificate and install it on your server so that you website is also served over SSL i.e **https://** www.your-site.com

**Details** Source - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/security

Understand Security Issues:

HTTPS provides critical security and data integrity both for your websites and for the people that entrust your websites with their personal information. Use the Security Panel in Chrome DevTools to debug security issues and ensure that you have properly implemented HTTPS on your websites.

If the requested page is retrieved over HTTPS, but the page then goes on to retrieve content from other origins using HTTP, then the page is still flagged as not secure. This is known as a mixed content page. Mixed content pages are only partially protected because the HTTP content is accessible to sniffers and vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Know all about making your site secure:(SSL)

What is an SSL Certificate?

SSL Certificates are small data files that digitally bind a cryptographic key to an organization’s details. When installed on a web server, it activates the padlock and the https protocol and allows secure connections from a web server to a browser. Typically, SSL is used to secure credit card transactions, data transfer and logins, and more recently is becoming the norm when securing browsing of social media sites.

Reference:

https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/

This is how Chrome shows a website before SSL:

[image: Site before SSL]

This is how Chrome shows a website after SSL:
[image: Site after SSL Certificate]

A tip: browsers give an error or block resources on websites which are served over https but request resources over http. One should avoid non secure resources on secure sites.